# Can you take action against a miserable pass-rate of an exam?

Tags: germany, education

At my university (germany) recently this happend.

The first exam had a failure-rate of 58% (265 paticipants), after the bound to pass was lowered.
The second exam had a failure-rate of 93% (111 paticipants).

Obviously the exam was in both cases to hard, and in my opinion this is unfair against everyone who took the exam.

I want to ask, if you can take an action against such results.
I have never witnessed so far an exam where the pass-rate was below 50%, and 93% not passing is just absurd.

Can something be done?

Comment: You'd have to ascertain whether the exam was unreasonably difficult or the teaching inadequate. If you just make the exam easy to pass, perhaps a future employer will sue for awarding a "fake degree" to one of its useless employees.

Comment: No, the claims in this question are absurd. The point of the exam (hopefully combined with other assessments, though I do not know how it works in Germany) is to separate competent students from those who are not competent, and if it so happens that 93% are not competent (due to failures of teaching, or other failures on the part of the students), so be it. It may well be that the exam is too hard, but it is hardly “obvious”.

Comment: @BrianDrake: I fully agree. I would *not* want to fly in an airplane knowing that the engineering exam's standards were lowered just to get half of the engineers to pass. I would not want to be treated in a hospital knowing that the MD treating me only passed because the standards for competency were lowered. The point of an exam is to prove that you are competent in the field, depending on the exam proving that you are competent enough to understand next year's classes, competent enough to enter the profession, etc. The standard is the standard.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Exactly. In my country, and I assume in lots of others, too, there have been discussions about lowering the difficulty level of exams to reduce the burden on the current students who spent a significant portion of their college education with no in-person lectures, in-person colloquiums, not being allowed to meet up and study with other students, etc. But the result of that is just going to be that no employer is going to hire someone who graduated in 2022. Employers have actually told me so.

Comment: The year after I started, the exam in Analysis 1 had a 90% failure rate. Without that particular exam, you might as well go home. There was a lot of pressure from other maths professors, and the exam was repeated. Identical to the first one, with 90% success rate, and universal agreement that if you failed, you fully deserved it.

Comment: Brian, I think with the numbers, 93% of those falling the first exam failed the second one.

Comment: As already noted, the failure rates you describe are pretty normal and generally accepted in at least some fields in Germany (including at least maths and physics). I have myself organised an exam with similar rates and I will happily explain to you why. However, since this would exceed the space and purpose of a comment, the answer may be interesting to others, and I like to read my own writings, I invite you to ask about this on [academia.se].

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think you misunderstand that the point of an engineering undergraduate degree (or medical degree) is to demonstrate to employers that you are capable of learning, know the basics, and can now be taught on the job to be an engineer. No graduate engineer designs an aeroplane - they help much more experienced engineers to do so.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think you mean 93% of those *passing* the first exam failed the second one. That would be consistent with the participant count of 111. If we assume (with a bit of rounding) that 103 participants failed the second exam, that would make the overall failure rate 97%. This is an important distinction, but not really important for this question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Done: [“Why might it be a good idea for exams to have a low (below 10%) pass rate?”](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/183700/131672)

Comment: @BrianDrake I think it more consistent with the German system that the second exam was the repeat try for the first. I don't think you can conclude either or the other from the numbers alone though, since there are some people who for scheduling or other reasons only attend the repeat try and similarly some who give up completely after failing the first.

Comment: @BrianDrake: My assumption was that students have to pass either of exams instead of both – which is a common procedure in Germany. While the numbers exactly fit, experience says that it is very unlikely that if 111 students can participate in an exam, they all do. But only the asker can really clarify that.

Comment: @BrianDrake I wouldn't be surprised at all if some numbers got mixed up. 111 is exactly 42% of 265. But the ones who passed the first exam would have had no need to enter the second one. Only if you fail the first exam, you need to take your second chance.

Comment: This pass-either-exam idea sounds weird to me (as a graduate of an Australian university), but if you all say that’s how it’s done in Germany, I’ll take your word for it.

Comment: @BrianDrake This pass-either-exam may not be what you think. The principle exam will be in, say, February, and then another one in April. Same subject, same content and different exercises, obviously. It is enough to pass one exam. In fact, usually students who passed in February cannot try again in April in order to get a better grade. Now, how does it work in Australia? What do you do if you have failed an exam? You obviously can't pass both the exam and a make up exam anymore.

Comment: @laolux Your question made me realise that I had never actually looked into it, and perhaps don’t understand it as well as I thought. I know that at my own university, students who have problems with assessments (exams or otherwise) due to extenuating circumstances can apply for special consideration. Also, in some cases, students with poor results are offered supplementary assessments. There is no automatic right to resit failed exams, as there seems to be in Germany. (I think this sort of discussion really belongs on Academia.)

Comment: @BrianDrake: there is also no universal right to resit an exam in Germany, but many (most?) written exams have this. From the lecturer's perspective: you anyways have to prepare such a 2nd exam for all those who were sick (or had other extenuating circumstances). So offering it to those who failed as well doesn't make much of a difference - otherwise, they'd show up in the next "normal" instance of the exam. (just in case: there is no per-course tuition or anything the like). Note also, that grading and pass/fail is typically on a pre-specified scale, e.g. 50+% of the total "points" => pass.

Comment: @DaleM re "know the basics": I'm chemist. The exams with e.g. 75 % of us failing on the 1st take were in the first semesters, covering exactly those basics. (And I'd say the reason for the high failure rate was that we hadn't yet adjusted to the difference between school and university, there was nothing unfair about those exams. See also the linked question on academia.)

Comment: BTW, in school we had certain "alarm levels": if in one exam too many were failing, the teacher would look (possibly with colleagues) into what happened, and sometimes it was *replaced* by a 2nd try (for the teacher ;-) if the first was considered actually too difficult) taken by the whole class. But also that was not automatically bound to the grade distribution. I remember a physics course where we could vote for the topic. Relativity theory won (although the teacher warned against the diffculty), and the exam grades were a disaster. However, the exam was considered fair, so no retake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**, the result of an exam is *not actionable*.
The court could only make a decision whether *legal* proceedings were met.
However, the grader’s decision whether a particular answer (and thus the overall exam’s result) was correct or incorrect is *not* legal in nature.
There is no German law saying “1 + 1 = 2”.
Therefore, the court could not make a ruling on that, nor is it really their task to do so.
Similarly, it is not the court’s (or the legal system’s) responsibility to ensure a certain share of students pass the exam.

> […] 93% not passing is just absurd.

Welcome to Germany.
Such exams did and do exist.
I refer you to the local student’s body (specifically the *Fachschaft*).
They will advocate for (future) students, especially if there are “design flaws” with the class to be found.
Unfortunately, if it’s the “examiner’s fault”, there are no other options than finding an *amicable* solution.
Sometimes, students *change* universities just to pass a certain module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a little bit shocked by this. How ever, where I study I have never seen an exam that had a pass-rate of lower then 50%. Also I thought that an exam has to have a pass-rate of 50% (by lowering the bound further and further), but this seems to be misinformation. As I said, I find it very much unfair, that students depend on the professor that much. While there are very gentle exams, and now a very "evil" exam. I hope that this was only for the freshman, to give them a shock early on. So they try harder next term.

Comment: Actually, in principle it is quite _good_ that education – schools and universities – enjoy autonomy and freedom in their own matters. Teacher and educators can exercise their profession pretty much without the threat of liability or state interference. On the other hand, though, it’s certainly a terrible feeling to be “at the mercy” of a teacher. Yet different standards apply if the school is _obligatory_: There you could potentially sue the state if it did not appoint a competent teacher and thus ensuring students could in general pass an exam. Such a trial would need _good_ evidence though.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that research and teaching at universities enjoys strong constitutional protections. A court will not and cannot prescribe what or how a professor will teach or how they should hold exams. Pretty much the only thing that students can legally ensure is that an exam takes place so that they can complete their studies.

Comment: You can design an exam so that people either pass it easily (if they understand the material and are clever enough), or they have no chance to pass (if they don't understand the material or are not clever enough). With such an exam, it could easily happen that 90% passing the first exam pass the second one, and 90% failing the first exam fail the second one.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocado I witnessed an exam with 90% failure rate. I was in an exam with about 75% failure rate; however you could take the exam, study the results, learn what you had missed, argue with the professor that you should have received more points, and doing that I just managed to get exactly 25 out of 60 points that you needed to pass. I think lots of people ended up with exactly 25 points :-) You just needed to be _very_ well prepared at that discussion.

Comment: In Germany, law schools’ study statutes usually provide for a _Remonstrationsrecht_, i. e. a right to appeal an exam’s result. It’s a quite formal process: You’ll first need to attend a session, a lecture, where the examiner minutely explains “the” correct answer. Then (usually within two weeks) you can file a complaint explaining where and why the grader “incorrectly” assessed your answer. After that _the examiner_ will _reevaluate_ your exam and possibly adjust the grade. Unfortunately, I haven’t seen this process in STEM subjects, possibly because the acceptable answers are pretty limited.

Comment: I think its worth pointing out that this isn't something that's particularly specific to Germany. To me (studied in denmark & uk) It's something that seems so normal that I am surprised to find that this *isnt* something that the OP has experienced. Specifically the idea of hard math courses at the beginning of STEM degrees is almost universal.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt as chemist, I don't know how to what extent this is formal requirement or just customary, but: we (and later our students) could always go and look into one's own marked exam (Klausureinsicht) and students do argue about some points here and there.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocado: you may misunderstood the 50 % pass rate - for most exams, you need 50 % of the points to pass. This is entirely different from having 50 % of the students pass. And it is an important lesson in general: when working with percentages, always spell out what the denominator is. (Otherwise, you may end up with a correct answer to the wrong question)

Comment: I'm wondering: there is a possibly special type of exams that have direct legal relevance. E.g., when I was studying chemistry, we had to pass the *Sachkundeprüfung nach Chemikalien-Verbotsverordnung*. Other fields have *Staatsexamen*. Would these exams be subject to same "freedom of teaching" or are there limitations here? (I admit, this is slightly off-topic)